# display toast message in jsp page

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hello Can I ask for a working example using js fiddle to show a success message for displaying a toast. I am having trouble to bind toast and include it in my web page. I would thank you if someone can explain how to show a toast message on a button click in a jsp page.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the **[Toastr](https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr)**, see the [demos](http://www.methods.co.nz/misc/toast/toast-examples.html).

In head tag, add the css:

```
<head>
    <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/css/toastr.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
```

In body tag, add the js files:

```
<body>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/js/toastr.min.js"></script>
    <script>$('#invokesToastMessage').click(function () { toastr.success('message', 'title'); });</script>
</body>
```

After, just to use, try:

```
<button id="invokesToastMessage">
```

Answer (score 0):

toastr will take around **90KB**, instead I suggest you try this light and simple [ToastMaker](https://github.com/vivekweb2013/toastmaker) library which is only **1KB** in size.

```js
$('#mybutton').click(()=>{ToastMaker("This is a toast notification!")});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://unpkg.com/toastmaker/dist/toastmaker.min.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/toastmaker/dist/toastmaker.min.js"></script>


<button id="mybutton">Show Toast</button>
```